# How to reduce the space between table cells?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to reduce the space between the  cells in the row of names below a photo. I've tried everything I can find without luck. Can anyone tell me how to make the names sit closer together inside the table? I've made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/cxqar2tb/2/). I'm using bootstrap 3. Many thanks

The Html

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-6 center-block animated fadeInUp">

    <div class="results">
      <ul id="results">
        <!-- results appear here -->
        <h3>
 Image title
</h3>
        <div class="dark">
          <a href="page.php?page_id=241"><img src="http://www.fiji.travel/sites/default/files//styles/views-large-thumbnail/public/arial-of-island.jpg?itok=KZHGX6pJ" width="600" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
        </div>





        <small>posted by:

                                         <a href="profile.php?user_id=user_id" span="" class="">
                                                Anderson</a></small>

<!-Make These names sit closer together--->
        <table id="myTable2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table" style="width:auto;">
          <tbody>

            <tr style="\&quot;display:none;\&quot;">
              <td valign="top"><strong><a href="profile.php?user_id=6" class="tags" style="color:">
                                                Anderson,</a>&nbsp;</strong></td>
              <td valign="top"><strong><a href="profile.php?user_id=9" class="tags" style="color:#3cb0fd">
                                                James Bond,</a>&nbsp;</strong></td>
              <td valign="top"><strong><a href="profile.php?user_id=2" class="tags" style="color:">
                                                Julian,</a>&nbsp;</strong></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css:

```
#myTable2 td {
  padding: 0 0;
}
```

it will remove the padding that you want to get rid of, and the cells will be right next to each other.

Comment: This worked perfectly on the fiddle I made but not on my page (whoch uses  a bootstrap template).

Answer (score 0):

You need a CSS reset script.  Whenever you build a new site, make this the topmost CSS script.  It will set padding and margins to zero on all elements.  On table cells, default padding is typically 2px.

There are others, but this one's not a bad start.  From http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```